# How to repair a terminal, once having been set to "set term xterm", to open X-Window and not showing just a messy code?

Tags: macos, gnuplot, x11, xterm

I'm using MacBook Pro running OSX 10.10 with XQuartz installed.

The Gnuplot version is 4.6.5.

After setting the terminal to xterm by typing "**`set term xterm`**", I can only get messy code in the terminal without other windows showing up.

**Anyone knows how to solve it?**

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the xterm terminal works only when also gnuplot was started from an xterm. Otherwise I do also see the 'messy' characters:

1. Call `xterm`.
2. Call `gnuplot`
3. Rund `set terminal xterm; plot x` on the gnuplot command line.

But do you really want to use the `xterm` terminal? I think using any other terminal like `wxt`, `qt` offers more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, that works! You are right. I thought xterm is the same as x11 since I don't have x11 in the terminals list. wxt and qt are both missing too. Now I have to think about installing these two terminals.